# Angular Kendo DatePicker: Select Month and Day without Year

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui, telerik, angular8

How do I disable year in Angular Telerik DatePicker component?
I am trying the following, and its not working. https://www.telerik.com/forums/datetimepicker-select-month-and-day-without-year

Currently trying to apply this in the Html place and hide year,

```
<kendo-datepicker format="MMMM"
[formatPlaceholder]="{ month: 'mm', day: 'dd' }"
></kendo-datepicker>
```

I want to only select/display Month and Day, Without Year.

Year should be gone in picture below,

Update:

**Final Solution which works:**

```
openDatepicker(e: any) {

// timeout for waiting until rendering is done
setTimeout(() => {
  const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.k-calendar tbody th');
  headers.forEach(el => {          
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.split(' ')[0];          
  });        
}, 0);
}

<kendo-datepicker 
    format="MMMM" 
    [formatPlaceholder]="{ month: 'mm', day: 'dd' }"
    (open)="openDatepicker($event)"
    >
    <ng-template kendoCalendarHeaderTitleTemplate let-title>
        {{title | slice : 0 : -4}}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoCalendarNavigationItemTemplate let-title let-date="date" let-view="activeView">
        {{view === 'month' && date.getMonth() === 0 ? 'Jan' : title}}
    </ng-template>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have quickly made a little [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2ker3) that shows a working solution:

The possible date formats you can find here:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl#date-formatting

And here the placholder documentation:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/placeholders/

**Edit:**

Two solutions:
First - hiding just the year is possible by manipulating after the calendar has renderd. 
Second - you can hide the line completely by adding the following code to the component:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: ['.k-calendar tbody th { display: none; }'],
```

ViewEncapsulation has to be set to None because otherwise the styles will not take effect. The style will just act inside of the component. If you want to have that globally just add the style to the global styles.css.

See both solutions in the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2ker3-iye58g)

**Final Solution which works:**

```
openDatepicker(e: any) {

// timeout for waiting until rendering is done
setTimeout(() => {
  const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.k-calendar tbody th');
  headers.forEach(el => {          
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.split(' ')[0];          
  });        
}, 0);
```

}

```
<kendo-datepicker 
    format="MMMM" 
    [formatPlaceholder]="{ month: 'mm', day: 'dd' }"
    (open)="openDatepicker($event)"
    >
    <ng-template kendoCalendarHeaderTitleTemplate let-title>
        {{title | slice : 0 : -4}}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoCalendarNavigationItemTemplate let-title let-date="date" let-view="activeView">
        {{view === 'month' && date.getMonth() === 0 ? 'Jan' : title}}
    </ng-template>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

Comment: Do you mean in the popup of the date picker? You can use a template for the header title: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/templates/

Comment: You can just hide it completely by adding this to your styles.css: .k-calendar tbody th {
    display: none;
}

Comment: hi , I still see year in the stackblitz, only need one stackblitz, without No year references

Comment: yes, I see the link above, I still see year all over, there should be No reference to year ever

Comment: see picture in question

Answer (score 0):

Will you try?

```
<kendo-datepicker format="MMMM" [formatPlaceholder]="{ month: 'mm', day: 'dd' }">
  <ng-template kendoCalendarHeaderTitleTemplate let-title>
    {{title | slice : 0 : -4}}
  </ng-template>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

We can arrange this in the left side;

```
<kendo-datepicker format="MMMM" [formatPlaceholder]="{ month: 'mm', day: 'dd' }">
        <ng-template kendoCalendarHeaderTitleTemplate let-title>
            {{title | slice : 0 : -4}}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template kendoCalendarNavigationItemTemplate let-title let-date="date" let-view="activeView">
            {{view === 'month' && date.getMonth() === 0 ? 'Jan' : title}}
        </ng-template>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

Comment: hi Mehmet, I tried this, see picture above, it is still showing year,

Comment: I've already done it by looking at the sections in the screenshot you added. You can check the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyqvz5).

Comment: hi Mehmet, do you have any update, getting close, is there way to remove year above in picture? thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Combine the codes from the link @Ludwig with the codes I prepared. You can get exactly the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

The CalendarHeaderTitle template provides the content for the header element on top that is always visible while scrolling through the content. It does not affect the content of all month-separator elements between the different months.

The layout can be customized by overwriting the built-in CSS, for example:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [`
  .k-calendar tr th[scope="col"]::after {
    content: '2000';
    background: white;
    color: white;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 31px;
  }
`]
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhd8tt-lwsims?file=app/app.component.ts

The sample styling can be further adjusted as necessary.